# Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, datetime

I have a MSSQL database and I want to date data (column name `Zeitstempel`) write on the display by use php. But I got this error :

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Why am I be getting such an error?

```
date_default_timezone_set(Europe/Berlin) ;
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                              
                     "PWD"=>$pwd,                              
                     "Database"=>$databaseName);   

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);    

$tsql = "SELECT Zeitstempel FROM statistik where mpid=1 ";    

/* Execute the query. */    

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);    

if ( $stmt )    
{    
 echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";    
}     
else     
{    
 echo "Error in statement execution.\n";    
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
}    

/* Iterate through the result set printing a row of data upon each iteration.*/    

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))    
{    
echo "Col1: ".$row[0]."\n";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because sqlserver `date` type is converted to php `DateTime` type

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296193.aspx

Use `format` method `$row[0]->format('...')`

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score -1):

try this its work for you

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))    
{    
  echo "Col1: ".$row[0]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";    
}
```

Comment: You just copied my answer? :)